# Dynamically change dotnet Core logging level

Tags: logging, asp.net-core-2.0, ef-core-2.0

Many 1:m queries expressed with EF Core are evaluated as a loop over the 1 side of the relationship, with the child query evaluated for each parent.

This produces a *lot* of info logs on the debug console, swamping other logs.

One can trivially turn logging off altogether: [Disable .NET Core EF 2.0 Query Logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47451291/disable-net-core-ef-2-0-query-logging) and this greatly speeds query evaluation in the debugger, but it doesn't help if you just want to exclude the query evaluation so you can find the other logs.

Presumably the logger is created by a builder somewhere and managed by the dependency injection container. Does anyone know how to get a reference to it and diddle the logging level?

Comment: See [Log filtering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?tabs=aspnetcore2x#log-filtering) for ASP.NET Core and [Filtering what is logged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/logging#filtering-what-is-logged) for EF Core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although Ivan's advice leads to helpful documentation, I've changed my mind about how best to approach the larger problem.

Running a separate query for the children of each parent row is a strategy that mitigates peak working set at the cost of higher overheads. This is good for a heavily loaded SQL server, and not so good for the network or client. In terms of throughput from the client's perspective, it's dismal.

*If* you need the entire result, materialise the parent rows into an array and use LINQ to get a distinct array of key values. Then query for the child side, exploiting conversion of array.Contains to IN () to run a single query using the index. Materalise this as a local array and then use LINQ to join the parents with the children in memory and project the result.

This approach produces runs two SQL queries so the log pollution stops. It has much lower set-up and tear-down overheads, but higher transient memory demands. The total amount of data shipped is roughly the same, except for the join key which must be shipped in both parents and children.

In the case with which I was dealing, this change of strategy brought execution time down from thirty seconds to half a second with logging disabled, and from ten minutes to half a second with logging enabled - it takes a while to write the same *long* query to the console 600 times.

The data producing the above figures contains 600 parents and 2800 children.